# ¿Cómo puedo separar los estilos de una misma etiqueta <a>?

Tags: html, html5, css3, scss

lo que pasa es que tengo definido unos estilos para una etiqueta a, el problema es que tengo más de una vez definida dicha etiqueta, y lo que quiero es que los estilos solo tomen una solamente, por ejemplo:

En la imagen tengo una etiqueta a en conjunto con un icono y una etiqueta h1. Por el otro lado tengo diferentes etiquetas a dentro de un nav.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y estos son los estilos que tengo definidos para la etiqueta a

```
a{
    display: block;
    height: 4rem;
    width: 25rem;
    background: #fff;
    color: #333;
    border-radius: 5rem;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2rem;
    line-height: 4rem;
}

a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    background: red;
    letter-spacing: .5rem;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Lo que quiero saber específicamente, es como hacer que los estilos que tengo definidos, solo tomen la etiqueta a que está dentro del nav y que ignoren la otra etiqueta a.

Comment: ¿has probado a usar clases o identificadores?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En css, puedes anidar elementos, clases e ids de elementos.

Puedes ver algunos ejemplos aquí:

- http://www.w3big.com/es/css/css-grouping-nesting.html

En tu caso, para que aplicase el estilo, a todas las etiquetas "a", dentro de tu "nav", podrías anidar la clase del "nav", con los elementos "a":

```
.navbar a{ 
   aquí tus estilos
}
```

o directamente las etiquetas "nav", con las etiquetas "a".

```
 nav a{
   aquí tus estilos
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias estimado, tu respuesta me ayudo muchísimo!.

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres solamente cambiar el css de la etiqueta  dentro del nav puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
.navbar a{
   //tu estilo css
}

nav ul li a{
  //tu estilo css
}
```